# Saving and loading list as csv file in Python 2.7.11

Tags: python-2.7, file, csv, save, load

I'm new to python. I've got a list called `bank` that can be something like this:

`bank = [["matt", "passw", 500, {apple:3}], ["luke", "passw123", 800, {google:2}]]`

1st parameter: name (`string`)

2nd parameter: password (`string`)

3rd parameter: cash amount (`float`)

4th parameter: dictionary (dynamic, I can change keys and values with other functions) (I don't know how to save it, if you can tell me how to do it I appreciate it, I commented it on the code).

At the beginning, `bank` is a blank list and with a function called `add_account` it adds a new list with for parameters. My goal is to create a .csv file, save `bank` in it and if I close the program, when I reopen it I want to load the .csv file with all the information of `bank` saved before.
These are the function that you need to know to solve the problem that I'm about to tell you:

```
import csv

def loaddata():
    f = open('bank.csv','r')
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        bank.append(row)
    f.close()

def savedata(bank):
    f = open('bank.csv','a')
    for account in bank:
        print account
        #4th parameter is wrong, i don't know how to save the dicionary
        st = '%s,%s,%f,%s\n' % (account[0], account[1], account[2], account[3])
        f.write(st)
    f.close()

bank = []
try:
    bank.append(loaddata())
except IOError:
    print "creating bank"



def add_account(bank):
    new=create_account()
    bank.append(new)

def create_account():
    new_account = [0,0,0,0]
    new_account[0] = raw_input('name ')
    new_account[1] = raw_input('psw ')
    new_account[2] = input('balance ')
    new_account[3] = {}
    return new_account
```

The problem is when I invoke `savedata(bank)` to save it in a file, and then I invoke `loaddata(bank)` to restore the previous `bank` data, `bank` was saved as a single string, and so I cannot use for example the 3rd and the 4th parameters because they are seen as string and not as float and dictionary. Also, when I try to invoke `savedata(bank)` the second time, it doesn't work (it says that as a 3rd parameter wants a float instead of a string) of course. How can I solve it? Thank you in advance.

Last thing: `savedata(bank)` function creates an object called `none` other than the one passed with "st" and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend writing the `bank` out to a `pickle` file, which is a binary format that is not human readable, but is very easy for python to read back in without having to worry about what should be a `string` and what should be  an `int` etc. There is a lot of documentation if you google python pickle.

So that a human can read it you might as well save `bank` as a csv file too when you save it as a pickle, so you can inspect what you've actually saved.

```
import pickle
import csv

def save_bank(bank, f_stem):
    """
    Function to save out the bank
    Pass in the bank and a file stem 'f_stem' like 'bank1'
    This function will then save a 'bank1.csv' and a 'bank1.pickle'
    """
    #Save out a csv of the bank so it's human readable
    with open(f_stem+".csv", "wb") as out_csv:
        csv_out = csv.writer(out_csv, bank)
        csv_out.writerow(['Name','password','money','misc']) #Write out a header
        for account in bank:
            csv_out.writerow(account) #Write out each account as a row

    #Save out a pickle of the bank so it's python readable
    pickle.dump(bank, open(f_stem+".pickle", "wb"))


def load_bank(f_stem):
    """
    Function to load in the bank
    Only needs the file stem used to save out the bank, i.e. 'bank1'
    """
    bank = pickle.load(open(f_stem+".pickle", "rb"))
    return bank


#Make a test bank
test_bank = [["matt", "passw", 500, {"apple":3}],
             ["luke", "passw123", 800, {"google":2}]]


f_stem = "bank1"
save_bank(test_bank, f_stem) #Save out the test_bank
new_bank = load_bank(f_stem) #Read it back in as a new bank

#See if the read out and in are identical
print "Bank written and read correctly:", test_bank == new_bank

#Print out the new bank read back in
print new_bank
```

Output:

```
Bank written and read correctly: True
[['matt', 'passw', 500, {'apple': 3}], ['luke', 'passw123', 800, {'google': 2}]]
```

Thank you for the complete question, let me know if something is wrong or poorly explained.